# how to get a particular value from NameValueCollection's comma-delimited string?

Tags: c#

i have a POST request

```
firstname=1&lastname=10&firstname=2&lastname=20&firstname=3&lastname=30.
```

then i get comma-delimited lists of names and values

```
Request.Form["firstname"] // 1,2,3
Request.Form["lastname"] //10,20,30
```

it seems that NameValueCollection does not contain a method to access specified firstname value directly?

the task looks standard, like Request.Form index property in ASP.

of course i can implement a custom helper enumerator or simply parse strings someway, but i'm not sure there are no any standard solution.

to be honest, i would prefer to have direct access to each firstname-lastname pair, but i cannot ask impossible:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetValues()` will return a `string[]`

Answer (score 0):

But how could you specify first firstname to the second one ?

they are not specific in this case. so you should write your own helper method to get the one you want.

Or replace keys with something like firstname1, firstname2.

Or if you get these from an radiolist control or listbox control, just use instance of the control to get the values, it's better solution I think.

Answer (score -1):

Split the string , then you'll receive an array containing the values.

```
string[] firstnames = Request.Form["firstname"].Split(",");
string[] lastnames = Request.Form["lastname"].Split(",");
```

Although I must admit that I find this a bit an ugly solution...  It's fragile imho.